# How do I match a number inside square brackets with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a regular expression which I expect should work but it doesn't.

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\])')
```

JavaScript is giving me the error：

> Invalid regular expression :(/(?<=[)[0-9]+(?=])/): Invalid group

Does JavaScript not support lookahead or lookbehind?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should work:

```
var regex = /\[[0-9]+\]/;
```

---

*edit*: with a grouping operator to target just the number:

```
var regex = /\[([0-9]+)\]/;
```

With this expression, you could do something like this:

```
var matches = someStringVar.match(regex);
if (null != matches) {
  var num = matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Only the first bracket needs to be escaped, technically.

Answer (score 2):

Lookahead is supported, but not lookbehind.  You can [get close](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), with a bit of trickery.

Answer (score 1):

To increment multiple numbers in the form of lets say:

```
var str = '/a/b/[123]/c/[4567]/[2]/69';
```

Try:

```
str.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function(m, p1){
 return '['+(p1*1+1)+']' }
)

//Gives you => '/a/b/[124]/c/[4568]/[3]/69'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're quoting a RegExp, watch out for double escaping your backslashes.